youtube video player full screen
 Align(
                            alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.0, 0.0),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Align(
                                    alignment:
                                        AlignmentDirectional(0.71, -0.92),
                                    child: FlutterFlowYoutubePlayer(
                                      url: 'https://youtu.be/T9IT4Q_aMKk',
                                      width: () {
                                        if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                            kBreakpointSmall) {
                                          return 110;
                                        } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context)
                                                .width <
                                            kBreakpointMedium) {
                                          return 130;
                                        } else if (kBreakpointLarge != null) {
                                          return 150;
                                        } else {
                                          return 200;
                                        }
                                      }()
                                          .toDouble(),
                                      height: () {
                                        if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                            kBreakpointSmall) {
                                          return 110;
                                        } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context)
                                                .width <
                                            kBreakpointMedium) {
                                          return 130;
                                        } else if (kBreakpointLarge != null) {
                                          return 150;
                                        } else {
                                          return 200;
                                        }
                                      }()
                                          .toDouble(),
                                      autoPlay: false,
                                      looping: true,
                                      mute: false,
                                      showControls: true,
                                      showFullScreen: true,
                                      strictRelatedVideos: false,
                                    ),
                                  ),

The youtube video player widget enters full screen when the user double taps the video. I want the video to go full screen on single tap.
There is no specific action in the widget. The double tap property seems to be inbuilt in the widget.

"I want the video to go full screen on single tap." Do you know how to detect a single tap? Do you know how to programmatically make the YouTube widget fullscreen? What are the remaining issues stopping you from implementing this?

I am new to flutter and am using flutterflow for the framework and code. I do not know how to re-program the widget to change its base functionality.

Will "fullScreenByDefault: true," give me the required functionality?
